# UIMA Ruta Workbench picks up an incorrect descriptor path

Tags: eclipse, uima, ruta

I am new to UIMA Ruta. I try to run the Main.ruta in the ExampleProject came with Ruta 2.1.0 source release using Eclipse 3.7 according to the instruction. It seems the Ruta workbench picks up an incorrect descritor path. I tried to set new Arguments in the "Run Configurations". It doesn't work.

Due to some restriction at work, The UIMA Ruta plugins were installed manaully.

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: what error do you get exactly?

Comment: This problem will not occur in UIMA Ruta 2.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An error because of incorrect descriptor paths indicates that the plugin are correctly installed, but the descriptors themselves are not updated.
The descriptors use some absolute paths in their parameter configuration. Try to build the project twice in order to regenerate all descriptors, e.g, with Menu->Project->Clean. Then investigate the descriptor ExampleProject/descriptor/uima/ruta/example/MainEngine.xml and check if the absolute paths are correct (pointing to your workspace project), especially the parameter scriptPaths.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Peter. The problem truns out that Ruta workbench can't handle spaces in descriptor paths. I fixed the space problem and the rebuilt the project. Now it works.

Comment: The problem with the spaces in the path is also fixed in UIMA Ruta 2.2.0